# how to create a ebs Elastic Beanstalk application using mariadb

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, aws-ebs

How can i create an EBS Elastic Beanstalk application using Mariadb instead of MySQL? Is this feature available? If not is there a place we can vote for this feature?

Comment: EBS, Elastic Beanstalk and Mariadb don't relate to each other. They are separate services. AWS RDS supports MariaDB.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev thanks i notice but how to make EBS work

Comment: Any details what specifically doesn't work? In general EBS service works fine and many people use it.